# jQuery mobile / Flot / resize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, flot

I am wondering if there is a compatibility problem between JQM and Flot.
I've looking for documentation about this, but there is not a lot...

Here is the issue: depending on the order in which I load the libraries, things work while others don't:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder" style="width: 60%;height:40%"></div>
```

--> Here the chart is not displayed: "Uncaught Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 671, height = 0"

Now if I remove JQM:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder" style="width: 60%;height:40%"></div>
```

--> Here the chart is displayed and the resize works, so I guess this problem comes from JQM but I have no idea what...

I've tried to load things in different orders, but nothing helps.

Does anybody know a workaround for this ?

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%; /* make the percentage height on placeholder work */
    }
    .message {
        padding-left: 50px;
        font-size: smaller;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body> 

<h1>Flot test</h1>
<div id="placeholder" style="width: 60%;height:40%; text-align: center; margin:0 auto;"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    var c1_values = [[0, 0],[1, 1],[2, 4],[3, 9],[4, 16],[5, 25],[6, 36],[7, 49],[8, 64],[9, 81],[10, 100],[11, 121],[12, 144],[13, 169],[14, 196],[15, 225],[16, 256],[17, 289],[18, 324],[19, 361]];

    var c1_data = [{ data: c1_values, label: "curve1"}];

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [
        {
            data: c1_values,
            lines: { show: true, fill: false }
        }
    ]);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am currently trying this "no conflict" function, but no result for now.

Comment: Did you try using jQuery.noConflict() ?

More about that, here http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Please show the code where you are actually displaying the chart.

Comment: Just tested "no conflict", that was a good try but the problem is still there... thanks for the idea. Additionally I've added the full code to the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile automatically wraps all your content in a `page` if you don't include on yourself.  Generally, that means you ought to do it yourself in your code!  So, first step is to move your placeholder into a jQM template:

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Flot test</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->
  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="placeholder" style="width: 60%;height:40%; text-align: center; margin:0 auto;"
    /></div>
  <!-- /content -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Now, it seems to be a common problem that the `content` div does not stretch to fill the whole available vertical space.  I found two solutions, neither of which seem very ideal.

1. Use CSS to try and make the `content` div full height (note that `data-role"content"` becomes a CSS class of `ui-content`):

   .ui-content {
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     position:absolute;
   }
2. Use Javascript to fix the content height dynamically as you go along (do this before your flot call).  Taken from [here](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/jquery-mobile-full-height-content.html):

   var fixgeometry = function () {
     /* Some orientation changes leave the scroll position at something

   - that isn't 0,0. This is annoying for user experience. */
     scroll(0, 0);

     /* Calculate the geometry that our content area should take */
     var header = $(".ui-header:visible");
     var footer = $(".ui-footer:visible");
     var content = $(".ui-content:visible");
     var viewport_height = $(window).height();

     var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();

     /* Trim margin/border/padding height */
     content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
     content.height(content_height);
     }; /* fixgeometry */

   $(window).bind("orientationchange resize pageshow", fixgeometry);

Neither of those solutions seemed to work particularly well for me, although they both did "work" as far as showing the graph.

I've posted an example of the 2nd version here:  http://alpha.jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/mz24P/

The CSS is there as well, commented out if you want to try that instead.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I'll keep both solutions and see which one is better in most situations. Many thanks, that is great!